# what is the correct way to splice an array using for loop, having nested if conditions

Tags: javascript

i am facing this issue of splicing an array.i checked out all the examples i could find but all in vein. the troubles are these nested if conditions inside the for loop .i am doing i-- but not able to go ahead. can anybody help me out and explain the approach.i am adding a snippet. the prob is that, whenever i don't do the i-- operation, and splice the array, alternate removal of elements happens but upon adding the i--, i am not able to proceed any further. i tried --i, but now i am confused as to what i am doing wrong! here m is an array of number from 1 to 20 serially. having length 20.

```
        var k=13;
        for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            if (m[i] < k) {
                if (i != 0 && i != m.length) {
                    m.splice(i, 1);
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    m.splice(i, 1);
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Which conditions should be met for splice to happen?

Comment: element at that index should be less than k=13

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read, you want to `filter` out all elements lesser than 13.
You can do the same by using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in javascript

```
const filterLimit = 13;

// Here filteredList is the list of all elements lesser than filterLimit
const filteredList = m.filter(item => item >= filterLimit);
```

Example:

```js
const filterLimit = 13;
const unFilteredList = [1, 13, 14, 2, 5, 33];

const filteredList = unFilteredList.filter(item => item >= filterLimit);

console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: may be. i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in this approach and that's you must not change the parameter `(i)` of the loop inside the loop

You can use `while` instead:

```
var k=13;
var i=0;
while (i < m.length){
    if(m[i] < k){
        m.splice(i, 1);
    }else{
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, can you explain why same approach with for loop is not correct?

Comment: Good ans. But is there a way with for loop?

Comment: Because editing the index variable of the **for** loop (i) inside the loop will cause unwanted behavior, and this applies for **almost** all programming languages, and also the foor loop always increases the index, but if you delete an item that means the index should stay the same, that's why in the **while** loop i increased the index just in the _else_ part